# Data storage in C# WPF MVVM application, like Redux in Web application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am writing my first WPF MVVM desktop application in C#.
I have many years of experience in creating React apps with Redux.

When I select a warehouse from a list, I want to request the related articles from the database.
After that, when I type the article number in an input, It needs to get the article from the list I just requested.

When using redux in a React app, you can store the list with articles in the store.
But how can I achieve this kind of data storage in a C# desktop application?

I use a Symphony backend as REST API for the data in de desktop application.

I have searched the internet but fount nothing useful.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting here. are you expecting someone to share code sample to your scenario?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Hi, I would like to know If it is possible and how I can create that kind of local data store.
If someone provides information or code that gives me a starting point, I will be very happy.

Comment: Any reason you need to have a local data storage?

Comment: I don't want to do a request to server every time I enter a article number, to receive the article data.